# How to get return values and output values from a stored procedure with EF Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SearchMovies]
    --@Year     int = null,
    @CategoryIds varchar(50) = null,
    @Keywords nvarchar(4000) = null,
    @PageIndex int = 1, 
    @PageSize int = 2147483644,
    @TotalRecords int = null OUTPUT
As ...
```

EF Repository:

```
 public class EFRepository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : BaseEntity
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _ctx;
    private  DbSet<T> entities;
    string errorMessage = string.Empty;

    public EFRepository(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        this._ctx = context;
        entities = context.Set<T>();
    }     
   ...

    public IQueryable<T> ExecuteStoredProcedureList(string commandText, params object[] parameters)
    {          
        _ctx.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(commandText, parameters);
        return entities.FromSql(commandText, parameters);
    }
}
```

I call this like:

```
var pCategoryIds = new SqlParameter()
            {
                ParameterName = "@CategoryIds",
                Value = commaSeparatedCategoryIds,
                DbType = DbType.String
            };
var pKeywords = new SqlParameter()
            {
                ParameterName = "@Keywords",
                DbType = DbType.String,
                Value = name
            };
var pPageIndex = new SqlParameter()
            {
                ParameterName = "@PageIndex",
                DbType = DbType.Int32,
                Value = pageIndex
            };
var pPageSize = new SqlParameter()
            {
                ParameterName = "@PageSize",
                DbType = DbType.Int32,
                Value = pageSize
            };

var pTotalRecords = new SqlParameter();
pTotalRecords.ParameterName = "@TotalRecords";
pTotalRecords.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
pTotalRecords.DbType = DbType.Int32;

var query1 = _ctx.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("dbo.[SearchMovies] " +
                "@CategoryIds, @Keywords, @PageIndex, @PageSize, @TotalRecords OUTPUT", 
                pCategoryIds, pKeywords, pPageIndex, pPageSize, pTotalRecords);

var query2 = _ctx.Set<MovieItem>.FromSql("dbo.[SearchMovies] " +
                    "@CategoryIds, @Keywords, @PageIndex, @PageSize, @TotalRecords OUTPUT",
                    pCategoryIds, pKeywords, pPageIndex, pPageSize, pTotalRecords);
```

`query1` does get the output `pTotalRecords` fine, but no return values, and the second `query2` gets the return values but no output parameter.

In EF 6, we used to have `SqlQuery` to do both actions in one command, how can I do the same in EF core ?

**UPDATED**:

Temporarily, I run 2 query, one to get the output param and one for result set.

```
 public IQueryable<T> ExecuteStoredProcedureList(string commandText, params object[] parameters)
    {          
        _ctx.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(commandText, parameters);
        return entities.FromSql(commandText, parameters);
    }
```

Comment: What's your MovieItem model? Does it have the exact same properties as returned by the stored procedure?

Comment: so you meant with Fromsql it can return output param ? ExecuteSqlCommand will return a integer, and in stored proc, SELECT  m.* ... from dbo.MovieItem m which is exactly the same as MovieItem entity.

Comment: As of EF Core 1.x, EF Core only supports result values which map to an existing entity and no fields can be missing from that entity. See the [EF Core roadmap](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/wiki/Roadmap): _**Raw SQL queries for non-Model types** allows a raw SQL query to be used to populate types that are not part of the model (typically for denormalized view-model data)._

Comment: I don't have problem to get the results as I said above, using FromSql I get all results back ok except TotalRecords which is a rowcount. And It seems EF core still lacks this feature, as I've googled for hours and no one has an example for this. See http://dotnetthoughts.net/how-to-execute-storedprocedure-in-ef-core/

Comment: Have you tried to use pure ADO.NET (System.Data.SqlClient) ?

Comment: @Herl I think it would work but I've invested hard work on this Entity framework, I'll wait for new future updates.

Comment: I am also stuck with that row count of `OutPut` parameter. Not working with this `FromSql(...)`

Comment: @namvo that was a bug - parameters were disposed before the reader closed. I see it have been fixed on AUG 1, 2017 https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/pull/9308/commits/003f0ceaa8b1c48bcf8c5b5381f8016cfa8d99de Do you still encounter this issue?

Comment: @DmitryPavlov thanks for your info. It seems to be a patch in version 2.0.3 as mentioned here https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/9309 , 2.0.3 is not out yet.

Comment: @namvo did you figure out how to return multiple parms using Database.ExecuteSqlCommand?

Answer (score 28):

I did something like this :-

-- My stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE p1
AS
     BEGIN            
        RETURN 29
     END
GO
```

C# code

```
SqlParameter[] @params = 
{
   new SqlParameter("@returnVal", SqlDbType.Int) {Direction = ParameterDirection.Output}
 };   


_stagingContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("exec @returnVal=" + storedProcName, @params);

var result = @params[0].Value; //result is 29
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks. I needed to do a simple GetDate() call to the DB, which isn't so easy in EF Core. This solves it for now.

Comment: my question is how to return both data set and output value, not just only output var

Comment: Could you please explain, why you chose ParameterDirection.Output instead of ParameterDirection.ReturnValue? p1 is returning 29 as a 'simple' return value and not as an output parameter.

Answer (score 11):

I am working to convert some EF6 code to EF Core, and ran into this same issue. In Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore version 2.1.0 the following use of `FromSql()` does return a result set and set the output parameter. You have to use `.ToList()` to force the proc to execute immediately, thereby returning both the results and the output param.

This is a sample from my DbContext class:

```
private DbQuery<ExampleStoredProc_Result> ExampleStoredProc_Results { get; set; }
public IEnumerable<ExampleStoredProc_Result> RunExampleStoredProc(int firstId, out bool outputBit)
{
    var outputBitParameter = new SqlParameter
    {
        ParameterName = "outputBit",
        SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Bit,
        Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
    };

    SqlParameter[] parameters =
    {
        new SqlParameter("firstId", firstId),
        outputBitParameter
    };

    // Need to do a ToList to get the query to execute immediately 
    // so that we can get both the results and the output parameter.
    string sqlQuery = "Exec [ExampleStoredProc] @firstId, @outputBit OUTPUT";
    var results = ExampleStoredProc_Results.FromSql(sqlQuery, parameters).ToList();

    outputBit = outputBitParameter.Value as bool? ?? default(bool);

    return results;
}
```

The stored proc returns the following entity:

```
public class ExampleStoredProc_Result
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Here's the stored proc:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ExampleStoredProc 
    @firstId int = 0,
    @outputBit BIT OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SET @outputBit = 1;

    SELECT @firstId AS [ID], 'first' AS [NAME]
    UNION ALL
    SELECT @firstId + 1 AS [ID], 'second' AS [NAME]
END
GO
```

Hopefully anyone that comes across this post in the future finds this useful.

Comment: Thanks this was the awnser for me. Works in EF Core 6 to.

Comment: Now, for .net core6, I use FromSqlRaw(commandString).ToListAsync()
 instead of  FromSql(...).ToList().

Answer (score 4):

map into context as keyless entity

```
    modelBuilder
.Entity<yourentity>(
    eb =>
    {
        eb.HasNoKey();
        eb.ToView("procname");
    });
```

add a dbset

```
   public DbSet<yourentity> yourentity { get; set; }
```

exclude it from migrations

```
  modelBuilder.Entity<yourentity>().ToTable("procname", t => t.ExcludeFromMigrations());
```

then in context can execute it into the mapped type

```
var values = context.yourentity.FromSqlRaw("EXECUTE dbo.procname");
```

Answer (score 3):

Late response, but may be useful for someone:

My stored procedure:

```
create procedure GetSomething(@inCode varchar(5), @outValue int OUTPUT)
as
Set @outValue = 1
end
```

In C#,

```
SqlParameter[] parameters =
{
   new SqlParameter("@inCode", SqlDbType.Varchar { Direction = ParameterDirection.Input, Value = "InputValue" }),
   new SqlParameter("@outValue", SqlDbType.Int { Direction = ParameterDirection.Output })
}
dbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw("exec GetSomething @inCode, @outValue OUTPUT", parameters);
var result = parameters[1].Value;
```

The keyword `OUTPUT` is important while calling from .net

Comment: Added bracket close for SqlParameters. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```cs
var results = ExampleStoredProc_Results.FromSql(sqlQuery, parameters).ToList();
```

`DbSet.FromSql` Enables you to pass in a SQL command to be executed against the database to return instances of the type represented by the DbSet.

This answer will done the trick for me.

Comment: FromSql is not efficient as all columns from the mapped table will be returned.

Answer (score 0):

While trying to call a stored procedure with one input and one output parameter using ExecuteSqlCommandAsync EF Core. I was avoiding using FromSql on the entity object. Below code worked great from me so just wanted to share on this old post.

```
    SqlParameter Param1 = new SqlParameter();
    Param1 .ParameterName = "@Param1";
    Param1 .SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarChar;
    Param1 .Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
    Param1 .Size = 50;
    Param1 .Value = "ParamValue";

    SqlParameter Param2 = new SqlParameter();
    Param2 .ParameterName = "@Param2";
    Param2 .SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarChar;
    Param2 .Size = 2048;
    Param2 .Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

    var sprocResponse = await _dbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommandAsync("[dbo].[StoredProcName]  @Param1= @Param1, @Param2 = @Param2 OUTPUT", new object[] { Param1, Param2});
    string outPutVal= urlParam.Value.ToString();
```